# What is the correct approach to solve this matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

We are given following matrix

```
5 7 9
7 8 4
4 2 9
```

We need to find maximum sum row or column and then we need to subtract 1 from each element of that row or column and then we need to repeat this operation for 3 times.

Comment: Have you tried finding the row or column with the maximum sum?

Comment: Yes, According to my understanding we can store row sum and column sum in two arrays and get the max from these two arrays and repeat this process three times.

Comment: Is there any dynamic programming concept can be used here to reduce the complexity?

Comment: @PradeepMaurya can you be more clear on the condition `find maximum sum row or column`. What are you going to do if the max sum row and column is same or you find multiple row and columns with same maximum?

Comment: If the max sum of any row or any column is same, in this case, we can select either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain.

The matrix is n*n and the increment process is repeated for k times. 
An *o(n^2+k×log(n))* algorithm is possible.

If the sum of the biggest row/columns is a row so:

1. The row sum is increased by *n*.
2. All columns sum is increased by 1.

The two rules apply for columns as well.

For rule one store all rows/columns sum in 2 AVL Trees
(or every other data structure that support *o(log(n))* insert and remove)

For rule two store rows/columns number of operations. (just two integers)

Now take the max of both trees where the two integers play a role for difference of the data staractures. Change it and change the other it and insert back.